# appmenu for other window managers/desktops

Tags: software-recommendation, appmenu, titlebar

I'm looking for an AppMenu like [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/oxygen-appmenu-replace-menu-with.html) for KDE to be used with GNOME or OpenBox or any other.

It provides a app menu in one button on the titlebar.

I have tried using KDE window manager in GNOME not very good.

Comment: Yes, never got an answer for this. how do I repost?

Comment: To keep the question alive and searching for answers. Please edit YOUR question, include details as what you have tried in order to resolve. Regards

Comment: Flag for closure removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For gnome-shell** 
To install appmenu in gnome shell add webupd8 ppa to the software sources 
press <kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>cntrl</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome3-globalmenu
```

[image]
[image]

**Links**

1. http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-gnome-shell-global-menu-in.html
2. https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Design/Whiteboards/AppMenu

Comment: Well this is close not in the window bar through, but excepted.